# Bootstrap 3: input-group mixed with non input-groups different sizes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

If a form has multiple controls in it, with some of the controls being a part of input-group divs and others not, is there a way to make them all take up the same space? My goal is to have all of the inputs the same width (the width of the controls that have the addons).

Here's my non-working attempt:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10 input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8XhCL/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
   <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
      <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Email</label>
      <div class="col-xs-10">
         <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
   <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Password</label>
   <div class="col-xs-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
   </div>
</form>
```

Put the a new div with the class `"input-group"` separated of the div with the class `"col-xs-10"`